# PDFJS NODEJS: Unable to silence warning messages

Tags: node.js, pdf.js, pdfjs-dist

I am using `pdfjs-dist` to extract plain text from pdf documents and would like to silence the following warning message from printing on the console:

```
Warning: TT: undefined function: 32
```

While this [post](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/issues/11292#issuecomment-548279413) states that I can do so by setting `verbosity: 0`, it doesn't seem to work, ie the warning messages are still getting logged on the console.

Code:

```
const pdfjslib = require('pdfjs-dist');

let options = {
    url: url,
    httpHeaders: {
        //headers
    },
    verbosity: 0,
}

function getPlainBody(options) {
    var loadingTask = pdfjslib.getDocument(options)
    return loadingTask.promise
    .then((doc) => {
        //handle doc
    })
}
```

The version of pdfjs-dist I'm using is 2.2.228 and I write in nodejs.

Comment: Just FYI, `verbosity: 0` worked for me

Comment: verbosity: 0 worked for me as well

Answer (score 1):

Update the value to 0 for the verbosity property under the defaultOptions in the viewer.js

```
verbosity: {
value: 0,
kind: OptionKind.API },
```

I have tried in version 2.6.347.